# Localize bitmaps and other pictures in Delphi projects?

Tags: image, delphi, bitmap, localization

I am using Delphi XE3 built-in localization tool. It seems that it can localize the strings. But I do not find a way to localize the bitmaps and other images that used in the project. The document also not mention this. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Let the bitmaps and picture in external file, then use a filename which will be translated to load the images.

Comment: Or put the images in a resource DLL and provide a different DLL for each language.